# Angular Material Table multiple sticky rows

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

As per official documents we can use `sticky` input for `sticky header` row in `mat-table`. But I need to make top 3 rows of mat table to be sticky. Is there any way to do that?

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the top 3 rows which you need to make sticky... where are those rows coming from? the TS file or static content which we can make part of the HTML?

Comment: I am getting all data from the service. So these rows are dynamic. However if required I can write some code to separate first 3 rows from the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about creating an array for the first 2 rows (which you need in the sticky header), after which you can remove these 2 rows from your actual data set (using `shift()`)...

relevant **HTML**:

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. 
        <div *ngFor="let data of firstTwoRows; let i = index">
          <p *ngIf="i<2">{{data.position}} </p>
      </div>
     </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name  
        <div *ngFor="let data of firstTwoRows; let i = index">
          <p *ngIf="i<2">{{data.name}} </p>
      </div>
</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight  
        <div *ngFor="let data of firstTwoRows; let i = index">
          <p *ngIf="i<2">{{data.weight}} </p>
      </div>
</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol  
        <div *ngFor="let data of firstTwoRows; let i = index">
          <p *ngIf="i<2">{{data.symbol}} </p>
      </div>
</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

relevant **TS**:

```ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * @title Table with sticky header
 */
@Component({
  selector: "table-sticky-header-example",
  styleUrls: ["table-sticky-header-example.css"],
  templateUrl: "table-sticky-header-example.html"
})
export class TableStickyHeaderExample {
  displayedColumns = ["position", "name", "weight", "symbol"];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  firstTwoRows: PeriodicElement[] = [];
  constructor() {
    this.firstTwoRows = [
      { position: 1, name: "Hydrogen", weight: 1.0079, symbol: "H" },
      { position: 2, name: "Helium", weight: 4.0026, symbol: "He" }
    ];
        this.dataSource.shift();
        this.dataSource.shift();
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: "Hydrogen", weight: 1.0079, symbol: "H" },
  { position: 2, name: "Helium", weight: 4.0026, symbol: "He" },
  { position: 3, name: "Lithium", weight: 6.941, symbol: "Li" },
  { position: 4, name: "Beryllium", weight: 9.0122, symbol: "Be" },
  { position: 5, name: "Boron", weight: 10.811, symbol: "B" },
  { position: 6, name: "Carbon", weight: 12.0107, symbol: "C" },
  { position: 7, name: "Nitrogen", weight: 14.0067, symbol: "N" },
  { position: 8, name: "Oxygen", weight: 15.9994, symbol: "O" },
  { position: 9, name: "Fluorine", weight: 18.9984, symbol: "F" },
  { position: 10, name: "Neon", weight: 20.1797, symbol: "Ne" }
];
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkpkqq)